# Navigating directories

Tags: python

After getting the path to the current working directory using:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

How would one go up one folder: `C:/project/analysis/` to `C:/project/` and enter a folder called data (`C:/project/data/`)?

Comment: Use ```os.path.dirname(<path>)```

Comment: @ewong that will simply give them the directory name of a given path - it doesn't allow them to access files in the other directory.

Answer (score 1):

In general it a bad idea to 'enter' a directory (ie change the current directory), unless that is explicity part of the behaviour of the program.
In general to open a file in one directory 'over from where you are you can do `..` to navigate up one level.

In your case you can open a file using the path `../data/<filename>` - in other words use relative file names.

If you really need to change the current working directory you can use `os.chdir()` but remember this could well have side effects - for example if you import modules from your local directory then using os.chdir() will probably impact that import.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), you could try this:

```py
os.chdir("../data")
```

Comment: You probably need to remove 'project' from the string, since you won't go up 2 directories